# RxJS run 2nd stream with the output from first stream

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I've got a service, which determines the location, it's written as Observable

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

const GEOLOCATION_ERRORS = {
    'errors.location.unsupportedBrowser': 'Browser does not support location services',
    'errors.location.permissionDenied': 'You have rejected access to your location',
    'errors.location.positionUnavailable': 'Unable to determine your location',
    'errors.location.timeout': 'Service timeout has been reached'
};

@Injectable()
export class GeolocationService {
    public getLocation(opts): Observable<any> {
        return Observable.create(observer => {
            if (window.navigator && window.navigator.geolocation) {
                window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                    (position) => {
                        observer.next(position);
                        observer.complete();
                    },
                    (error) => {
                        switch (error.code) {
                            case 1:
                                observer.error(GEOLOCATION_ERRORS['errors.location.permissionDenied']);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                observer.error(GEOLOCATION_ERRORS['errors.location.positionUnavailable']);
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                observer.error(GEOLOCATION_ERRORS['errors.location.timeout']);
                                break;
                        }
                    }, opts);
            } else {
                observer.error(GEOLOCATION_ERRORS['errors.location.unsupportedBrowser']);
            }
        });
    }
}

export var GeolocationServiceInjectables: Array<any> = [
    { provide: GeolocationService, useClass: GeolocationService }
];
```

Then in my HttpService I want to construct the query URL with the output from location service

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { GeolocationService } from './location.service';
import { WeatherItem } from '../weather-item/weather-item.model';

export const OpenWeatherMap_API_KEY: string = 'SOME_API_KEY';
export const OpenWeatherMap_API_URL: string = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {
    constructor(private http: Http,
        private geolocation: GeolocationService,
        @Inject(OpenWeatherMap_API_KEY) private apiKey: string,
        @Inject(OpenWeatherMap_API_URL) private apiUrl: string) {
    }

    prepaireQuery(): void {
        this.geolocation.getLocation({ enableHighAccuracy: false, maximumAge: 3 }).subscribe(
            (position) => {
                let params: string = [
                    `lat=${position.latitude}`,
                    `lon=${position.longitude}`,
                    `APPID=${this.apiKey}`,
                ].join('&');
              //  return `${this.apiUrl}?${params}`;
            }
        );

    }

    getWeather(): Observable<WeatherItem[]> {
        return this.http.get(/*there should be the url*/)
            .map((response: Response) => {
                return (<any>response.json()).items.map(item => {
                    const city = {
                        city: item.city.name,
                        country: item.city.country,
                    }
                    return item.list.map(entity => {
                        return new WeatherItem({
                            temp: entity.main.temp,
                            temMin: entity.main.temp_min,
                            temMax: entity.main.temp_max,
                            weatherCond: entity.weather.main,
                            description: entity.weather.description,
                            windSpeed: entity.wind.speed,
                            icon: entity.weather.icon,
                            city,
                        })
                    })
                })
            })
    }
}
export var HttpServiceInjectables: Array<any> = [
    { provide: HttpService, useClass: HttpService },
    { provide: OpenWeatherMap_API_KEY, useValue: OpenWeatherMap_API_KEY },
    { provide: OpenWeatherMap_API_URL, useValue: OpenWeatherMap_API_KEY }
];
```

The question is how to get the URL before doing request. I've seen solutions with unsubscribe(), but I think thay are not so good. I've thought about merge() but I'm not sure that it's what I really want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for the `mergeMap` operator of RxJs.

What `mergeMap` does is automatically subscribes to the source observable, then lets you work with its result in your inner observable, and then finally flattens your output.

In this example, you call the `firstUrl` and use the result you get from that request in your second call to `secondUrl`:

```
this.http.get(`{firstUrl}`)
   .mergeMap(res => this.http.get(`{secondUrl}/{res.json()}`))
   .subscribe(...)
```

I have not made it specific for your code, as I'm not sure of exactly what you want to do. But I hope this will help you on the way!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using `map`/`flatMap` combination:

```
getWeather(): Observable<WeatherItem[]> {
    return this.geolocation.getLocation({ enableHighAccuracy: false, maximumAge: 3 })
        .map((position) => {
            let params: string = [
                `lat=${position.latitude}`,
                `lon=${position.longitude}`,
                `APPID=${this.apiKey}`,
            ].join('&');
          return `${this.apiUrl}?${params}`;
        })
        .flatMap(url => this.http.get(url)
        .map((response: Response) => {
            return (<any>response.json()).items.map(item => {
                const city = {
                    city: item.city.name,
                    country: item.city.country,
                }
                return item.list.map(entity => {
                    return new WeatherItem({
                        temp: entity.main.temp,
                        temMin: entity.main.temp_min,
                        temMax: entity.main.temp_max,
                        weatherCond: entity.weather.main,
                        description: entity.weather.description,
                        windSpeed: entity.wind.speed,
                        icon: entity.weather.icon,
                        city,
                    })
                })
            })
        })
}
```

Comment: Just a note; `flatMap` is renamed to `mergeMap`. `flatMap` still works, as it is an alias for `mergeMap` though.